# iOS - EXC_BAD_ACCESS when executing a segue to MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, storyboard

I am using Storyboard-
I am pretty new to this-

I'm getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` <sub><sup>(`code=2`, `address = 0x4`)</sup></sub> error when I click a button pointing to a `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

To give you an idea of what I've got so far: I have several different `ViewControllers` all under the same `ViewController`.h/m class with navigation controlled by a `NavigationController`. I started with a `NavController` and single `ViewController` and have been linking new `ViewControllers` with the simple CTRL-Click button-to-new-`ViewController`. I added a new `ViewController`; changed it's class to `MPMoviePlayerViewController` in the Custom Class section of the Identity Inspector, but I keep getting this error when I click on the button to begin the transition.

Here's my `ViewController.h` code if it's relevant:

```
- (IBAction)postToTwitter:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Check this out!"];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [controller setInitialText:@"Posted from IOS App Test -- It works!"];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
}
- (IBAction)playVideo1:(id)sender {
    NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"link omitted"];
    //create our moviePlayer
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    //Some additional customization
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
    moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
}
```

Comment: What's the `@property` declaration for moviePlayer?- is it an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: @RichTolley

Code below, but the movie player isn't even accessed before the problem occurs. I'm just trying to get to the MPMoviePlayerViewController

`code`
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController * moviePlayer;


- (IBAction)postToTwitter:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)playVideo1:(id)sender;
`code`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how the hell to add newlines in these comments

Comment: You seem to have 2 `MPMoviePlayerController`s - one allocated programmatically as an ivar of a vanilla view controller, with its view as a subview of the vc's main view and one connected in a storyboard with a segue of some kind - maybe a push segue since you're using a navigation controller. It doesn't look like the two are connected, so if your segue is being triggered maybe the problem is to do with the one in the storyboard not being setup. I presume the segue button is also wired up to `-playVideo`?

Comment: The playVideo isn't called upon the segue;  I think I'm just misunderstanding the proper usage of the MPMoviePlayerViewController. I guess the better question was how to implement MPMVC with the way I've set everything else up. I'm going to dump this particular question and repose it differently. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Add the Exception breakpoint (use the plus button in the bottom left in the Breakpoints view in Xcode) and you should get more useful information from the debugger.